# KAFKA's topic message's timestamp cannot merge with the timestamp value within the Kafka's value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

[image]

Hello everyone, the above picture is how Databricks recommend people to connect the kafka topic message to a delta live table (DLT). My current situation is I have a kafka topic that I am subcribed to, but I cannot load directly in a delta live table.

My code is as below":

```
@dlt.table(name = "tableOne", table_properties={"pipelines.reset.allowed":"false"})
def stream_bronze():
    return(
    spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafkaserver address") #this is the kafka server address
    .option("subscribe","topic_name") #this is the topic name of the kafka server
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") #in order to properly "subscribe" to a kafka topic, you need to input the proper security protocals
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") #Like above
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", """kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="api key" password="secret";""") #This is where you need to input the Kafka API key (username) and the Kafka API secret (password)
    .load()
    )
```

When I run the above command, I get the error that there is an issue with merging the timestamp of the kafka message and the timeStamp of the kafka message value (so the content inside the kafka message. It goes by the format of a json).

The kafka schema that is fixed is like this:
[image]

And the schema of the details inside value looks like this:

```
schema = StructType([ 
        StructField("event", StringType()),
        StructField("ecommerce" , StringType()),
        StructField("gtm.uniqueEventId" , StringType()),
        StructField("eventId" , StringType()),
        StructField("eventType" , StringType()),
        StructField("pagePath" , StringType()),
        StructField("pageType" , StringType()),
        StructField("isRegistered" , StringType()),
        StructField("memberId" , StringType()),
        StructField("sessionId" , StringType()),
        StructField("campaignId" , StringType()),
        StructField("elabRecommType" , StringType()),
        StructField("elabRecommId" , StringType()),
        StructField("gaUserId" , StringType()),
        StructField("gaSessionId" , StringType()),
        StructField("siteCode" , StringType()),
        StructField("timeStamp" , StringType()),
        ])
```

The issue that I get is that timestamp from the kafka and timeStamp from the schema of the json inside of the kafka message's value is different. One is TimestampType and the second one is StringType.

The error message that I get is:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to merge fields 'timeStamp' and 'timestamp'. Failed to merge incompatible data types StringType and TimestampType
```

Of course, if I could modify the type directly from the kafka message producer it would be great but I do not have that kind of permission. Is there a way for me to make it possible fr the streaming of the kafka message successful on a delta live table?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:
I run the following code to apply the schema, but this is not really what is preventing me. even with this bit out. The action of simply asking the dlt to return the kafka readStream is not working. The error being the one mentioned above

```
wtchk_value_df = wtchk_kafka_df.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("value"))
```

Comment: it is never used. I am just using that bit of code to show how the content of format json looks like. I wrote 'schema' simply so that I can use from_json later on to explode the data that's from the kafka's message's value

Comment: If it's never used, then your error doesn't make sense because `timeStamp` is never compared against existing `timestamp`. Besides, you can always drop a column from a dataframe

Comment: More specifically, where is your code that casts the value column to a string and uses any json functions?

Comment: I added the code,. I used this to apply the schema, and it works, but the thing is if I load this  (wtchk_value_df ) into the DLT,, the written records stays static and I do not see an increase of it, despite the table running

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. We cannot see where `wtchk_kafka_df` is defined or where you actually call `stream_bronze()`... But as soon as you do `col("value").cast("string")`, you no longer have the top-level `timestamp`, so still your error isn't clear where it occurs